# Need ideas for simple closed circuit tv for church overflow room

Tags: video, video-recording

**The Need:** In our small church, we have an "overflow" room right across the hall from the main room where the pastor speaks. We're already getting sound into the overflow room separately, but we need to get video into there, too. We don't need recording capabilities, just a live video feed.

**Some challenges:** We did have a setup using a camcorder in the main room, and running an HDMI cable from the camcorder to a TV in the overflow room, which worked ok, but the camcorder recently broke. We could just buy a new camcorder, though it seems overkill to buy a camcorder with all its functions, when all we need is a live video feed. At the same time it would be nice to have something I can move and zoom with a remote (sometimes we need to switch views when there's a baptism, for example).

I even thought about using a cell phone or ipad with google hangouts or face-time, or chromecast. But I don't think I want to rely on wifi; plus, there will probably be a delay that then wouldn't sink with the sound that we're piping in separately. I was looking for closed circuit cameras online, but most of the stuff I found was either bad video quality (like some security cameras), or had all these bells and whistles that I don't need, like infrared night-vision, motion-detectors, etc.

So, here's a detailed list of needs/wants for the setup:

1. Live video feed to a separate room (no recording necessary, no sound necessary)
2. Decent video quality (not like some security cameras)
3. Remote move/zoom control
4. Ideally < $500
5. (optional) Wireless (nice to have, but NOT necessary)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remotely control the pan, tilt, and zoom of the camera, you want to look for a "PTZ" camera. You will not find one under $500 with a controller.

A cheap camcorder with a wall mount and a long HDMI cable is your cheapest option.

If your budget was closer to $2,000 you'd be able to get everything on your list.

Answer (score 0):

How about a wireless AV Transmitter?

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00BUKK8QA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BUKK8QA)

Comment: Please avoid link only answers. This should be a comment instead.

Comment: Also, you can trim that link to end at **...8QA/** since everything from **ref=** onward is cruft.

Comment: It is also worth noting that this does not help with the remote zoom/move control.  Some more explanation of the advantages/disadvantages of this solution would make this a much better answer.

Answer (score 0):

thats a tough one for the price, have you looked at GoPro cams? theres no zoom, but excellent quality. Probly could find one on ebay for around $200